# Fragment not coming null even when not in layout

Tags: android

I am developing a two pane App whose appearance changes based on screen orientation. In portrait mode, the app displays only a ListFragment. In landscape, I have both a ListFragment and a DescriptionFragment that contains only a TextView.

In portrait mode, when I click on an item in the ListView, the app should show me a description in another Activity that holds the DescriptionFragment.
On the other hand, in landscape mode, the description should appear in the DescriptionFragment in the same layout.

It works fine in portrait mode, and even when I switch to landscape. The problem appears when I return to portrait from landscape.

In the following code, fragment1 is the id of the DescriptionFragment in the layout. In portrait mode f is null and we go to another activity. When in landscape f is not null and it works. But when we return to portrait mode, f is not null but the TextView is null and the App crashes.

When we come back to portrait, why is it able to find the Fragment, even though it is not in the layout?

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_list);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Fragment f = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
                if (f == null) {
                    Intent p = new Intent(MyListActivity.this, DescriptionActivity.class);
                    p.putExtra("pos", i);
                    startActivity(p);
                } else {
                    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
                    if (tv != null)
                        tv.setText(citiesdata[i]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```